# How often do party members update their dialogue?

Tags: mass-effect

In Mass Effect 1, your party members have new stuff to say every now and then when we are on the Normandy. Is it updated on a regular basis or only when you do story based missions and progress further into the game?

I haven't seen a real pattern so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe your crew has new dialog options after every story mission. From what I recall the only side missions that affect crew dialog are the following crew specific side missions:

> [Garrus: Find Dr. Saleon](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Garrus:_Find_Dr._Saleon) and [Wrex: Family Armor](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Wrex:_Family_Armor)

Other than those missions, you can feel free to skip talking to your crew except when you finish story missions.